# MongoDB field order and document position change after update

Tags: mongodb

I am learning MongoDB and I noticed that whenever I do an update on a document the field being updated is pushed to the end of the order, so if I had something like:

```
db.collection.save({field1: value1, field2: value2, ..., field 10: value10});
db.collection.update({field1: value1}, {$set: {field2: new_value}});
```

then if you do:

```
db.collection.find();
```

it will display:

```
{ "field1":"value1", ..., "field10":"value10", "field2":"new_value"}
```

You can see how the field order changes where the updated field is being pushed to the end of the document. In addition, the document itself is being pushed to the end of the collectoin. I know that it's a "schema-less" DB and it may not be a huge problem, but it just doesn't look "pretty" :). Is there a way to do an in-place update without changing the order?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

MongoDB allocates space for a new document based on a certain padding factor. If your update increases the size of the document beyond the size originally allocated the document will be moved to the end of the collection. The same concept applies to fields in a document.

Comment: Bernie, Thanks! I understand the reason, but not the solution. If they, MongoDB, have to re-write the entire document to accommodate the new space requirements, why couldn't they preserve the field/document order in the process? Is there a performance penalty or is this something they just haven't had time to implement just yet? - just curious.

Answer (score 12):

FYI, in [MongoDB 2.6](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#insert-and-update-improvements) updates will preserve field order, with the following exceptions:

1. The _id field is always the first field in the document.
2. Updates that include renaming of field names may result in the reordering of
   fields in the document.

Comment: Would you know how to request the fields in a particular order (say alphabetically maybe) ?

Answer (score 5):

Both document structure and collection structure in MongoDB based on JSON principles. JSON is a **set** of key/value pairs (in particular fieldName/fieldValue for document and index/document for collection). From this point of view it doesn't seem that you can rely on order at all.

Comment: MongoDB relies on bson, not json and bson elements are ordered: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON

Comment: Order of keys can matter in mongo, certain find queries will return some results or no results depending on the order of the keys for nested documents. See devblog.me/wtf-mongo for example, and if the link ever dies, find it on wayback machine.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of the documents if the field size changes, it writes out a new document with the fields sorted by field name.
This behavior can be seen with the following statements

Case 1: No change in size of field, so no change in field order

```
> db.testcol.find()
> db.testcol.save({a:1,c:3,b:2})
> db.testcol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d5efc3bec5855af36834f5a"), "a" : 1, "c" : 3, "b" : 2 }
> db.testcol.update({a:1},{$set:{c:22}})
> db.testcol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d5efc3bec5855af36834f5a"), "a" : 1, "c" : 22, "b" : 2 }
```

Case 2: Field size changes and the fields are reodered

```
> db.testcol.find()
> db.testcol.save({a:1,c:"foo",b:2,d:4})
> db.testcol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d5efdceec5855af36834f5e"), "a" : 1, "c" : "foo", "b" : 2, "d" : 4 }
> db.testcol.update({a:1},{$set:{c:"foobar"}})
> db.testcol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d5efdceec5855af36834f5e"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : "foobar", "d" : 4 }
```

Is there a particular reason why you do not want the fields reordered? The above was using 1.8.0_rc0 on OS X

Comment: No particular reason, at least not yet, but I was thinking that if I would forget to add a "sort" option to my query, it could affect the way the code displays the data. Or if the code would use numeric arrays (even though it shouldn't), such as var[0], var[1], var[2], etc and the field order is changed, then it could also present a problem. I am just getting into this NoSQL "databasing", so I have questions like this popping-up all over the place in my head :)

Answer (score 2):

I've created a project that creates a custom mongorc.js which sorts the document keys by default for you. It's called [Mongo Hacker](http://tylerbrock.github.io/mongo-hacker/)

Comment: didn't know about Mongo Hacker.. awesome enhancements Tyler

Comment: I wonder how Mongo Hacker sorts the fields. A..Z? or saves extra metadata to the database? because both seem as bad options. A...z will sort `key_1, key_10, key_2` while extra metadata will eat more SSD/CPU/RAM + introduce new unknown fields in DB that may be overwritten by app logic. Can you give more clarity on how it sorts?

Comment: It doesn't save extra metadata. It does the sort on the client (shell) which is cheap. It uses no extra cpu/memory on the database but does use a negligible amount of cpu/memory in the client because most documents have a limited number of keys + nesting and it only sorts them as they are printed (coming out of the cursor). If the minimal cost is unacceptable to you there is an option to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the fields in the order I wanted, I inserted all the documents with the properties in the correct order to another Collection. Then I removed the old Collection and renamed the new Collection to the original name.
Obviously backup your data first.

Answer (score 0):

Raman , is right , we can't sort an dictionay , but we can sort the visualization of the dictonary, so we can't sort  filed order of an documentation , but I can see it ordered .

For example in perl to_json have option canonical

```
print to_json( $data, { utf8 => 1, pretty => 1, convert_blessed => 1, canonical => 1 } );
```

(canonical option) will output JSON objects by sorting their keys. This is adding a comparatively high overhead . (of course, we do more a sorting operation ...)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to yours where updating a field would push it to the end of the document. The only decent solution I could find was to perform:

1. an aggregation combining $replaceWith and $out stages. The $replaceWith stage handled the rearranging of the fields in all documents within the collection, and the $out stage writes the output of the $replaceWith stage into a new collection.
2. Then you would need to drop the old collection, and...
3. (optionally) rename the new collection.

I'm not sure if you could overwrite the collection on the $out stage by using the same name of the input collection and skip steps 2 & 3.

Otherwise, the commands would look something like this:

```
> db.oldCollection.aggregate([{$replaceWith: {field1: "$field1", field2: "$field2"... fieldN: "$fieldN"}}, {$out: "newCollection"}])
> db.oldCollection.drop()
> db.newCollection.renameCollection("oldCollection")
```

The order in which you define the fields in the $replaceWith stage is the order in which they will be outputted. And yes, the values of the fields should be the field names themselves prepended with $.

Comment: Can confirm, you can overwrite the input collection by using the same collection name on the $out stage.