# How to perform a dynamic document update in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

How can you perform a dynamic document update in MongoDB? (from the terminal application mongo, *not* by having to use additional libraries like mongoose for nodejs)

My first attempt didn't seem to actually update anything:

`db.people.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { myDoc.field = myDoc.field.replace(/\/./g, '/'); } );`

The update documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter only seems to discuss "static" updates (so you can't use the exist value of a document's attribute to determine what the new value should be).

Do I need to use the MapReduce feature some how?

Comment: You cannot update the value of a field based on the value of "another"  field at present. But surely what you are doing is simply a `regex` match on the selection side with a "fixed" value to update on the "update" side. So why cannot you simply do just that?

Comment: @NeilLunn the value is unique, so if I understand you correctly that would mean I'd be forced to run n queries for n documents which doesn't sound fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right approach to do this one doc at a time, but you need to call `save` on the collection to commit your change to `myDoc`:

```js
db.people.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { 
    myDoc.field = myDoc.field.replace(/\/./g, '/'); 
    db.people.save(myDoc);
} );
```

Comment: Additional observation after using this solution: the order of fields in output from `db.people.find()` which was consistent is now changed to almost the same as before, but with _id appearing first in the list. IDK what this means, if anything, but it makes me wonder what else changed about the document state after using `db.people.save()`

Comment: @Trindaz That's normal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046835/mongodb-field-order-and-document-position-change-after-update