# Insert field in particular order in existing mongodb collection. (Not Append)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to insert a field in existing collection in mongodb at particular order. For e.g. If I have collection which contains document as:

```
item:{ 
       //mandatory field, will exist in each document
       id: "1", 
       //non-mandatory fields, may or may not exist in each document 
       name: "john", 
       age: "22", 
       email:"john@gmail.com" , 
  }
```

Now I want to insert a field "gender" after age and before email so that my document becomes:

```
item:{
       id: "1",
       name: "john",
       age: "22",
       gender: "male",
       email:"john@gmail.com"
```

}

My collections is basically of a POJO generated from xsd, A document may or may not contain certain fields. Therefore I can't just override the json.

Comment: What's the point in having keys in order?

Comment: I have to generate xml using this data in proper order, if keys are not in proper order then xml will fail validation against the xsd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046835/mongodb-field-order-and-document-position-change-after-update

Comment: @JohnnyHK I am not updating existing field, i am inserting new fields. Also I did'nt find any solution in that post.

Comment: It's still the same issue. There isn't any way to control the order of the added field. You're probably best off tweaking the field order as you generate your xml.