# Mongoose create document in wrong key:value order according to schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I have a problem with understanding of how Mongo `.create` and `.findAndUpdate` operation works. I have mongoose 5.4.2X and a model with schema which has lot of `key:value` pairs (without any nested objects) in the exact order (**in the code below I use 1. 2. 3. etc to show you the right order**) like this:

```
let schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    1.code: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    2.realm: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    3.type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['D', 'M'],
    },
    4.open: Number,
    5.open_size: Number,
    6.key: typeof value,..
    7...another one key: value like previous one,
    8.VaR_size: Number,
    9.date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: true
    }
});
```

and a `class` object which have **absolutely the same properties in the same order** like schema above.

When I form data for Mongo via `const contract = new Class_name (data)` and using `console.log(contract)` I have a necessary object with properties in **the exact right order** like:

```
Contract {1.code: XXX, 2.realm: YYY, 3.type: D, .... 8.VaR_size: 12, 9.date: 327438}
```

but when I'm trying to create/update document to the DB via `findOneAndUpdate` or (findByID) it writes in alphabetical order but not the necessary 1->9, for example:

```
_id:5ca3ed3f4a547d4e88ee55ec
1.code:"RVBD-02.J"
7.VaR:0.9
(not the 1->9)...:...
8.VaR_size:0.22
__v:0
5.avg:169921
```

The full code snippet for writing is:

```
        let test = await contracts.findOneAndUpdate(
            { 
                code: `${item_ticker}-${moment().subtract(1, 'day').format('DD.MMM')}`  //how to find
            }, 
            contract, //document for writinng and options below
            {
                upsert : true,
                new: true,
                setDefaultsOnInsert: true,
                runValidators: true,
                lean: true
            }
        ).exec();
```

> Yes, I have read the mongoose docs and don't find any option param for
>   solving my problem or probably some optional params are matter but
>   there are no description for this.
>
> It's not my first project, the funny thing is, that when I'm inserting
>   tons-of-docs via `.insertMany` docs are inserted according to schema
>   order (not alphabetical)

My only question is:

> How do I fix it? Is there any option param or it's a part of `findAnd....`
>   operations? If there is not solution, what should I do if for me it's
>   necessary the right ordering and check existence of document before
>   inserting it?

Update #1 after some time I rephrase my search query for google and find a relevant question on SW here: [MongoDB field order and document position change after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046835/mongodb-field-order-and-document-position-change-after-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I found the right answer according to the link that I post earlier. So yes, it's part of MongoDB:

> MongoDB allocates space for a new document based on a certain padding
>   factor. If your update increases the size of the document beyond the
>   size originally allocated the document will be moved to the end of the
>   collection. The same concept applies to fields in a document.

by @[Bernie Hackett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600498/bernie-hackett)

---

But in this useful comment still no solution, right? Wrong. It seems that the only way to evade this situation is using additions optional params during `Model.find` stage. The same ordering using during `project` stage via `.aggregate` and it looks like this:

```
Model.find({query},{
   "field_one":1,
   "field_two":1,
   .............
   "field_last":1
});
```